# Sharing post to facebook from website and no image displays just a description in white box

Tags: facebook, sharing

When i try to share any page from my website with facebook all i get is a blank white box with just a description .
My web company have said the issue lies with facebook and not with them.
This is a page i have tried to share - https://eat-sleep-drink-frontend.vercel.app/restaurants-bars-glasgow-east-end  - and the following image comes up   [This is what my preview looks like for facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ts7f.png)   [Post to facebook on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TGxv.png)    [post to facebook on app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy3bp.jpg)

This is what facebook sharing debugger shows - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Feat-sleep-drink-frontend.vercel.app%2Frestaurants-bars-glasgow-east-end

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks rob

Looking across numeriouse forums and using facebook's sharing debugger but not sure what it all means or what im looking at in the Scraped URL